# How to complete validator execution?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a validator code. The problem that it does not perform
`if (_value == true)` statement, what is wrong with it?
It gives me `---------------- true` but does not output '///////////+++++++++++++++++++' or '///////////-------------------'.

```
validator: (val) {
  print('login page password: $val');
  if (val.isEmpty) return 'Wrong password';

  bool _value;

  locator<LocalStorageService>()
      .isValidPassword(val.trim())
      .then((onValue) {
    print('---------------- $onValue');

    _value = onValue;
  });

  if (_value == true) {
    print('///////////+++++++++++++++++++');
    return null;
  } else {
    print('///////////-------------------');
    return 'Wrong password';
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You have asynchronous code executing inside your validator, so when the execution reaches this line:

```
 locator<LocalStorageService>()
      .isValidPassword(val.trim())
      .then((onValue) {
    print('---------------- $onValue');

    _value = onValue;
  });
```

It calls `isValidPassword` and registers a callback (`then(...)`)

And it continues to the next code:

```
if (_value == true) {
    print('///////////+++++++++++++++++++');
    return null;
  } else {
    print('///////////-------------------');
    return 'Wrong password';
  }
```

immedialtely without waiting for the `Future` above to complete,

So now `_value` is still `null` because the `Future` didn't have time to return,so now the `else` block will be executed,

**Solution**: I suppose this is a `TextFormFieldValidator` and thus you can't `await`  the `Future` (else you will be returning `Future` from the validator which is forbidden), so you have to change your code that makes the validation to make it not dependent on a `Future`

learn more about how async code works [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY)

Comment: hm, is that the only solution?

Comment: you are using a function provided by the framework, and it forces you to return a `String`, and if you want to make a call to a `Future` you can't await it so your call will be useless,So yes that is the only solution if you want to keep using native `TextFormField`

Comment: if you are so insistent to use a Future, maybe you can implement a custom field

Comment: In case my background logic relies on future, sholud I change all that logic? because on every step I have to deal with futures.

Comment: yes, or you can try to implement your own `TextField` with validation